# DateComponents giving wrong hour

Tags: swift, nsdatecomponents

I am trying to implement a simple countdown timer in my test app.

I have two dates:

1. `fromDate` - which is current time that I get by Date(), e.g.  2021-08-27 11:07:34 +0000
2. `toDate` - is a future date, e.g. 2021-11-17 01:00:00 +0000

I am using `DateComponents` to get back the difference in days, hours, minutes and seconds.

```swift
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second],
                                                 from: fromDate,
                                                 to: toDate)
```

Its returning me back the values for days hours minute and second 81, 12, 52, 25

The values for day, minute and second are correct, but the hour is 1 hour less.

I suspect daylight timing has to do something with this but I cannot find anything that can help here.

Kindly help me what I am doing wrong as I have tried many things in past few days but nothing seems to work

Comment: Shouldn’t daylight savings have something to do with this?

Comment: Where you you? I mean what's your locale? Do you "change hour" in summer/winter? Could you check between these two dates if there is one (a quick Google Search should give you the answer). Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, the daylight savings do affect me.
But in this case won't that mean the hours should be 13 and not 12?

Comment: Both of the dates are in UTC (just fyi)

Comment: No they are not, they are just printed using that time zone. A Date object does not hold any time zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the behaviour by using:

```
let from = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1630062455)
print(from) // 2021-08-27 11:07:35 +0000
let to = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1637110800)
print(to) // 2021-11-17 01:00:00 +0000
var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "Europe/London")!
let comp = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: from, to: to)
print(comp.day!, comp.hour!, comp.minute!, comp.second!)
```

The reason why this happens is because when doing `dateComponents(_:from:to:)`, `Calendar` takes into account its timezone. After all, without a timezone, (almost) no date components would make sense - you would not be able to tell what hour a `Date` is, for example. A `Date` just represents an instant in time/n seconds since *the epoch*.

(In the case of `Calendar.current`, the timezone it uses is `TimeZone.current`)

[`Europe/London` would go out of DST at some point between `from` and `to`](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london). This means the calendar would calculate the difference in date components between:

```
from: 2021-08-27 12:07:35
to:   2021-11-17 01:00:00
```

Notice that the first time is 12:07:35, rather than 11:07:35. This is because at `2021-08-27 11:07:35 +0000`, the local date time at `Europe/London` really is `2021-08-27 12:07:35`.

To get your desired output, just change the calendar's `timeZone` to UTC:

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")!
let comp = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: from, to: to)
```